# Core Data not refreshing in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, core-data

I'm working on an app that uses a ForEach loop to display data stored using CoreData in SwiftUI. I've managed to make everything work, except, when I update the data within the view using the stepper, the data does not immediately update, but only updates after I restart the app.

I did my research and found that I have to use a predicate with @FetchRequest, but even that is not working.

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct HomeScreen: View {

    init(){
        UINavigationBar.appearance().largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor : UIColor.white]
    }
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc

    @StateObject var dataController = DataController()
    
    @FetchRequest(entity:Subject.entity(),sortDescriptors: [], predicate: NSPredicate(format: "attended != 0 OR missed != 0")) var subjects: FetchedResults<Subject>
    
    
    @State private var showModal = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack{
            ZStack{
                Color.black
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                    VStack(spacing:30){
                        ForEach(subjects){ subject in
                            VStack{
                                AttendanceCard(subject: subject.name ?? "Unknown", attended: subject.attended, missed: subject.missed, requirement: subject.requirement)
                                HStack{
                                    Stepper("Attended", value: Binding(get: {
                                        subject.attended
                                    }, set: { newValue in
                                        updateClasses(for: subject, attended: newValue, missed: subject.missed)
                                    }))
                                    Stepper("Missed", value: Binding(get: {
                                        subject.missed
                                    }, set: { newValue in
                                        updateClasses(for: subject, attended: subject.attended, missed: newValue)
                                    }))
                                }
                                .labelsHidden()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 60, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
                    .navigationTitle("Your Attendance")
                }
                .sheet(isPresented: $showModal) {
                    AddSubjectView()
                }
            }
            .toolbar {
                Button {
                    showModal.toggle()
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
                        .foregroundColor(Color(hex: "96EF1B"))
                        .shadow(color: Color(hex: "96EF1B"), radius: 5)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func updateClasses(for subject : Subject, attended : Float, missed : Float){
        subject.missed = missed
        subject.attended = attended
        try? moc.save()
        dataController.saveData()
    }
}
```

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class DataController : ObservableObject {
    static let shared = DataController()
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Stash")
    
    init(){
        container.loadPersistentStores { description, error in
            if let error = error {
                fatalError(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func saveData(){
        if container.viewContext.hasChanges {
            try? container.viewContext.save()
        }
    }
}
```

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct Watt_oApp: App {
    
    @StateObject private var dataController = DataController.shared
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            TabBarView()
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, dataController.container.viewContext)
        }
    }
}
```

I'd be very glad if someone could help me, thanks in advance

Comment: All CoreData objects are ObservableObjects so they need to be wrapped with ObservedObject if you want to see changes.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the relevant Entity with its Attributes?

Answer (score 0):

You are using two different instances of `DataController`, the shared one and the other in `HomeScreen`. This causes the issue.

In `HomeScreen` delete

<strike>@StateObject var dataController = DataController()</strike>

---

And replace `updateClasses` with

```
func updateClasses(for subject : Subject, attended : Float, missed : Float){
    subject.missed = missed
    subject.attended = attended
    DataController.shared.saveData()
}
```

The line

```
try? moc.save()
```

is redundant, and it seems that `moc` is not needed either.

Comment: Hey, I implemented everything you said but the same issue still persists. It doesn't automatically update the info in the HomeScreen. Am I doing something else wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There're a few things weird in your code:

1- You have an `ObservableObject` class and a singleton with `static let shared`. They're both doing the "same thing".

2- You have 2 identical functions with `func saveData()` and `try? moc.save()`. They're also both doing the "same thing".

But for your problem, here's a quick fix to make sure the content is updated the way you want: you can look for a simple variable that is toggled every time you use your function `updateClasses`.

```
struct HomeScreen: View {
    @State private var pleaseRefresh = false

    var body: some View {
        // Your content
    }

    func updateClasses() {
        // Your function
        pleaseRefresh.toggle()
    }
}
```

Not a perfect solution but it should works!